# How to convert xsd datetime to localDateTime with default time zone

Tags: java, xml, datetime

Valid xsd `datetime` values are:

```
2002-05-30T09:00:00
2002-05-30T09:30:10.5
2002-05-30T09:30:10Z
2002-05-30T09:30:10-06:00
```

When I tried to parse this values with `ZonedDateTime`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse(value, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime());
}
```

in first two values if fails because there is no timezone:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-12-05T10:05:19.296' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2017-12-05T10:05:19.296 of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

when I will use `LocalDateTime` it just ignore timezone in last two values.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("2002-05-30T09:30:10-06:00", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)); // print 2002-05-30T09:30:10  and I am in +1 timezone
}
```

So what is the correct way to convert this xsd datetime ?

**UPDATE**

so maybe the best solution to convert xsd:datime is to use old way to gregorianCalendar which also support zoneDateTime ?

```
public static LocalDateTime parseDateTime(String strVal) {
    try {
        if (strVal == null || strVal.isEmpty())
            return null;
        return ((GregorianCalendar) (DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(strVal))).toZonedDateTime()
                .withZoneSameLocal(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ZonedDateTime always require to have a timezone. The first two dates are missing it. What I would suggest is to encapsulate the logic in a separate class and if a zone is missing just add a 'Z' at the end as it's supposed to be a UTC date time. Your method will always return a ZonedDateTime and the client of the code will know nothing about how it's created.